# Python: how to test DataFrame with a mock df string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

if i have a dataframe output like this, that im trying to use as test data :

```
                                          Record     SD
0  section 11, column 14 (of 15), row 22 (of 28)   3.70
```

I want to format the test string to be like the df output. i have tried :

```
dfString = "\tRecord\tSD\nsection 11, column 14 (of 15), row 22 (of 28)\t3.70\n"
```

But it comes out misaligned like

```
Record  SD
section 11, column 14 (of 15), row 22 (of 28)      3.70
```

Comment: If you have tests that rely on the output *format* of your dataframes, you may want to revise your test (or code).

Comment: thats helpful, could u elaborate a little on that ?

Comment: But otherwise: what is the problem? What fails? I see a missing `0` and `1` at the start of a line, and the second line is missing, but those are obvious and easy to fix. What is it you're having a problem with?

Comment: The output *format* is (presumably) only seen (and interpreted) by humans. The *contents* of the dataframe, is what is handled in your code. Unless you are testing humans, and not your code, you should probably test with the *contents* of a (mock) dataframe.

Comment: thanks, i will revise the tests.

Comment: If you need a certain (precise) amount of spaces, you can use a width modifier. Example with an f-string: `print(f"|{' ':20}|")` yields `|                    |`.

Comment: awesome thank you!

Comment: @9769953 should i use a pandas series to test the data in the row?